# Detectar si un Entry está rellenado #Python #Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que rellenas unos campos y luego pulsas un botón para enviar y comprueba si has rellenado los campos, pero no sé como hacer la comprobación, he intentado con esto:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def función():
    if opción_radiobutton.get() == "1" or opción_radiobutton.get() == "2" and nombre.get() != "":
        messagebox.showinfo("Datos guardados", "Los datos se han guardado y enviado correctamente")

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width="900", height="600")
frame.pack()
opción_radiobutton = tk.IntVar()
tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="Hombre", variable=opción_radiobutton, value="1").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="Mujer", variable=opción_radiobutton, value="2").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(frame, text="Nombre:").grid(row=2, column=0)
nombre = tk.StringVar
tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=nombre).grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Button(frame, text="Enviar", command=función).grid(row=3, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Lo que pasa es que al pulsar el botón de enviar, no hace nada, i no sé como hacer-lo. Además en la parte de la función `nombre.get() != "":`
me dice que `.get()` necesita el valor `self` y no sé que valor tengo que pasarle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Antes que nada, te recomiendo que no utilices nombres de variables con acentos o caracteres especiales, a pesar de que python 3 lo soporta en [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#source-file-encoding) menciona que si la aplicación o programa es de uso global es mejor utilizar nombres de variables únicamente con valores ASCII

> All identifiers in the Python standard library MUST use ASCII-only
> identifiers, and SHOULD use English words wherever feasible (in many
> cases, abbreviations and technical terms are used which aren’t
> English).
>
> Open source projects with a global audience are encouraged to adopt a
> similar policy.

Fuera de eso, cuando declaras `nombre = tk.StringVar` te hace falta poner paréntesis `nombre = tk.StringVar()`

Y para evaluar los botones de radio basta con comparar si el valor es diferente de cero

Ejemplo completo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def fun():
    if (len(nombre.get()) != 0) and (radiobutton1.get() !=0):
        messagebox.showinfo("Datos guardados", "Los datos se han guardado y enviado correctamente")
        

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width="900", height="600")
frame.pack()
radiobutton1 = tk.IntVar()
tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="Hombre", variable=radiobutton1, value="1").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="Mujer", variable=radiobutton1, value="2").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(frame, text="Nombre:").grid(row=2, column=0)
nombre = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=nombre).grid(row=2, column=1)
tk.Button(frame, text="Enviar", command=fun).grid(row=3, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ahora funciona perfectamente